# How to store code/programs written in any programming language in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have to display some C# code on a page of my web application (ASP.NET MVC application). How can i store C# code (program) in SQL Server ? Consider that i have the following code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

How can i store this code in SQL Server, so that when my application reads the code from the database, the code can be displayed as it is on the page.

Comment: You can use varchar. A varchar field can store html tags too (or markdown version if you wish).

Comment: Why a `varchar` @CetinBasoz ? There could almost certainly be data loss with that data type; C# code won't just be limited to characters in a particular code page. `nvarchar` would be much better suited.

Comment: I have to display the above code on my page. You can consider, as the code is displayed on tutorials website, just like that i have to display the code on a page @CetinBasoz and Larnu

Comment: You can use nvarchar

Comment: Yes you can store tags in a varchar or nvarchar field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple SQL Server script demonstrating the concept of storing multi-line string data (such as a code snippet) in a database table:

```
create table CodeExamples(Id int identity(1,1), Code varchar(max));

insert into CodeExamples(Code) select 'public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}';

select * from CodeExamples;
```

Comment: Thanks @robbpriestley, it worked :). I was thinking about the formatting but table is giving me the formatted code, Thanks

Comment: No doubt the formatting you are concerned about is the newline character ('\n') which is just string (varchar) data like the rest of it in my example. It is unlikely you would need an nvarchar column for this unless your code samples featured text with accented characters, etc.